# Prolog: How to work with Global Array?

Tags: arrays, prolog, global-variables, swi-prolog

In SWI Prolog, I need to keep marking in the same global array, how do I achieve it?

My doubt is because, the global array will be overwritten everytime, isn't it?

I understand I need to use dynamic and assert to acheive it. But, since I am new to Prolog I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: You do not use an "array", you put your data in individual clauses, which you can store using `assert/1`.

Comment: Maybe Swi-Prolog's `nbsetval/2` and `nbgetval/2` but this is not the best way to use Prolog...

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is unclear. What problem are you trying to solve? Prolog doesn't have "arrays" but "lists". And a global variable isn't generally a good way to solve the typical Prolog task.